# Create control with vertical scroll bar fill container without horizontal scroll bar appearing

Tags: winforms, horizontal-scrolling, tablelayoutpanel, docking

I have table layout and inner table layout (marked with red braсkets).
When inner table have a few rows vertical scroll bar disabled and it fill cell(3 columns spawn).
However, when there is too many rows, vertical scroll bar is enabled and it take some space from container so horizontal scroll bar became visible also.
Is there is any way to make so that table layout with scroll bar and docking set to fill, have exact width of the container(3 columns in my case) after dynamic creation.
Images:
http://imageshack.com/a/img37/7370/jr04.png
http://imageshack.com/a/img850/3075/nmk3.png

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable horizontal scrollbar for table panel in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197452/how-to-disable-horizontal-scrollbar-for-table-panel-in-winforms)

Comment: Thanks a lot, exact what I tried to do.