# How to disable HorizontalScroll in flowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, .net

```
flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
flowLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
flowLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
flowLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
```

The above code is not working. How to disable HorizontalScroll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197452/how-to-disable-horizontal-scrollbar-for-table-panel-in-winforms)

```
int vertScrollWidth = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;

flowlayoutPanel1.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, vertScrollWidth, 0);
```

Or set

```
flowDirection=leftToRight
flowlayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false
wrapContents = true
```