# C# Tablelayoutpanel Hide horizontalbar

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I try to remove the horizontalbar of my tablelayoutpanel, and from the website, I found other people's solution to use padding.

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Padding p = TPSS_Signals.Padding;
        TPSS_Signals.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, vertScrollWidth, 0);
   }
```

But this solution doesn't make any change on my tablelayoutpanel TPSS_Signals
Could you please help me to find the reason?

Thank you Vidya, actually my code is from Bavarious in your link. But it doesn't work for my program

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197452/how-to-disable-horizontal-scrollbar-for-table-panel-in-winforms) can help you. There are 4-5 answers listed in the page and each of it has been marked helpful.